# DAX formula for - returning top n revenues

Tags: expression, dax, top-n

I'm trying to get the top 5 revenues from the column REVENUE in the Table SALES .
I have tried this but it's not correct because the expression is suppose to return multiple columns .

```
TOP_N_REV = TOPN(5;FACT_SALES; MAX(FACT_SALES[REVENUE]) ; 0 )
```

Any ideas ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `SUMX`

```
TOP_N_REV = SUMX(TOPN(5;ALL(FACT_SALES);FACT_SALES[REVENUE]);FACT_SALES[REVENUE])
```

Also might be related:
   http://www.dutchdatadude.com/power-bi-pro-tip-confusion-about-topn-versus-rankx/

Comment: Thank you for your reply . I have tried that but it's not giving me the result that I seek . still showing me all the revenues in a specific date.